# Visualizing buffer on 3D objects

Tags: 3d, buffer, visualization, arcgis

I have a shapefile of buildings (multipatch) in 3D. I also have a point file. I want to run a buffer on the point file to see until what point the buffer interacts to the buildings. Basically i want to visualize for specific distance what one can see from a point. if i do it in 2D with the buildings (polygon) file this is what i get. Can't seem to find a way to do it in 3D. Any ideas???

[2D example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcsUs.png)

[3D attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfft6.png)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is using the [ArcGIS API for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) and visualize each point as multiple transparent cylinders. This can be done using a [`PointSymbol3D`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-symbols-PointSymbol3D.html) with a [`ObjectSymbol3DLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-symbols-ObjectSymbol3DLayer.html) for each buffer distance:

```js
pointsLayer.renderer = new SimpleRenderer({
  symbol: new PointSymbol3D({
    symbolLayers: [
      new ObjectSymbol3DLayer({
        anchor: "center",
        width: 120, // 120m buffer distance
        depth: 120, // 120m buffer distance
        height: 70,
        resource: { primitive: "cylinder" },
        material: { color: [237, 248, 177, 0.6] },
        castShadows: false
      }),
      new ObjectSymbol3DLayer({
        anchor: "center",
        width: 70, // 70m buffer distance
        depth: 70, // 70m buffer distance
        height: 68,
        resource: { primitive: "cylinder" },
        material: { color: [127, 205, 187, 0.6] },
        castShadows: false
      }),
      new ObjectSymbol3DLayer({
        anchor: "center",
        width: 20, // 20m buffer distance
        depth: 20, // 20m buffer distance
        height: 66,
        resource: { primitive: "cylinder" },
        material: { color: [44, 127, 184, 0.7] },
        castShadows: false
      })
    ]
  })
});
```

Here is a live example using random points random points within 3D buildings: https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/d228b8e28614d4b48fd1d57d68d17418?editors=0010

[image: 3D buildings with buffers]

Depending on the number of points, you could also provide an interactive experience hiding buildings for a selected buffer distance. Check out this sample using client side filters: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-scenelayer-feature-masking/index.html